# The rn tags in RightNow

Tags: rightnow-crm

By searching the php code in the existing RightNow scripts, I have managed to put together a list of the various rn tags used and the attributes used.  I have searched high and low for some documentation on these tags to no avail.

Can somebody point me to where I would find some documentation on this?

For the benefit of others this is what I have found in the scripts:

```
<rn:
----
    condition
        sla
        logged_in
        answers_viewed
        searches_done
        chat_available
        config_check
        url_parameter_check
        show_on_pages
        hide_on_pages
        external_login_used
        language_in
        incident_reopen_deadline_hours

    condition_else

    widget (widget attributes will vary depending on the widget - those with a dash are included for standards adherence purposes)
        path
        -name
        -label_input
        -required
        -table
        -validate_on_blur

    meta
        title
        template
        login_required
        redirect_if_logged_in
        force_https
        clickstream
        sla_required_type
        sla_failed_page
        include_chat
        javascript_module
        answer_details
        controller_path
        compatibility_set

    theme
        path
        css

    field
        name
        label_input
        highlight

    page_title

    head_content

    page_content

    block
        id

    form
        post_handler
        action

    answer_xref

    answer_section

    container
        report_id


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#rn:
----
    msg
    session
    language_code
    php
    url_param
    url_param_value
    config
    php
    community_token

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you log into your Customer Portal admin site (whatever.custhelp.com/ci/admin), you can use the menu options to navigate to browse Page Tags / Page Meta tags under the Framework menu.  Under Widgets, you will find all the widgets available for your site.

You can also read through the technical documentation located at cx.rightnow.com; here is a [direct link to the answer page](https://cx.rightnow.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5169). Click on the Customer Portal portion and look under the Section titled "Customer Portal Template and Page Set".